# How to convert an Object[] type to Userdefined array type

Tags: java

I am creating the Leg Objects this way

```
List<Leg> legs = new ArrayList<Leg>(legdata.length);
```

I need to pass this legs to an method with the below signature as shown :

```
 public static String getStrategy(Leg[] leg)
```

when i did the below way i am getting an error .

```
String resultData = CMPUtil.getStrategy(legs.toArray());
```

Also tried this way

```
Leg les[] = (Leg)legs.toArray();  ( It says cannot cast from Object to Leg)
```

could anybody please let me know , how to resolve this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
String resultData = CMPUtil.getStrategy((Leg [])legs.toArray(new Leg[legs.size()]));
```

Comment: Thank you all very much , (Unfortunately i could select only one answer)

Answer (score 2):

Pass in an array of the right type to the [other overload of `List.toArray`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29):

```
Leg[] legsArray = legs.toArray(new Leg[0]); // Or new Leg[legs.size()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Leg les[] = legs.toArray(new Leg[legs.length]);